# Explicitly setting max jobs / flow limit on a BW sub-process

Tags: tibco

I know we can set max jobs and flow limit on a TIBCO starter process but is there anyway of explicitly setting it on a sub-process (non starter process)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max Jobs and Flow Limit can only be set on process starters or on spawned subprocesses. Flow control on regular (i.e. non-spawned) subprocesses is determined by the parent process starter's configuration and cannot be overridden.

If you want to be able to control the flow of a subprocess, I see 2 options:

1. Make it a spawnable process.
2. Make it an independent process with its own process starter (e.g. JMS Queue Receiver) and have the parent process invoke it with the
   appropriate protocol (e.g. JMS). This way you can control the
   process' flow control as you would do with any process starter.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with ***Nicolas***. However if for example let say that your flow allows 10 jobs max. to enter but then you want one job at a time to get executed, you could use a "Critical Section" to make sure only one job access the resources at any given time. (This is an example only)
[image: Flow-Limit-and-critical section]

"Critical section groups are used to synchronize process instances so that only one process instance executes the grouped activities at any given time. Any concurrently running process instances that contain a corresponding critical section group wait until the process instance that is currently executing the critical section group completes.

Critical Section groups are particularly useful for controlling concurrent access to shared variables (see Synchronizing Access to Shared Variables for more information). However, other situations may occur where you wish to ensure that only one process instance is executing a set of activities at a time. "

Comment: That's correct. Another option would be to use a Shared Variable as a counter and implement some logic so that only N jobs can execute the process at a time. The counter would be incremented each time a job enters the process and decremented when the job exits the process.